# PHPMotion - Do I need ffmpeg etc if I just upload in .flv?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, mpeg, motion

My shared host won't let me install ffmpeg and some similar libraries, will it work if I just upload in flv?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you link to the FLV from the PHPmotion script then yes.

Opinion: Find a host that allows ffmpeg as it will be quite a burden on potential users to encode their own FLV files.

Comment: Also, assuming that you don't have a streaming server your users will be subject to progressive downloading of the FLV files in question.